# Sorting items from same table

Tags: sql-server, sorting

Hi i've got this little issue while sorting items within our database.

table data is like this:

```
id  | description | parent | rowlevel
100 | item  12222 | -none- | 0
SET | item  12345 | -none- | 0
201 | item  22345 | -SET -  | 1
```

I'd like have to output sorted on "id" though also have it sorted on a way that the "childen" come after the "parents".

I know this would be easier with a different table layout though changing that is not an option.

planned result would be:

```
id  | description | parent  | rowlevel
100 | item  12222 | -none-  | 0
SET | item  12345 | -none-  | 0
201 | item  22345 | -SET -  | 1
301 | item  22345 | -SET -  | 1
401 | item  22345 | -SET -  | 1
ST2 | item  12345 | -none-  | 0
211 | item  22345 | -ST2 -  | 1
321 | item  22345 | -ST2 -  | 1
101 | item  22345 | -ST2 -  | 1
```

i've tried using order by but though its result has the rowlevel 1 items together the item's parent results at the bottom. together with the other parents.

I am not experiences using joins and have no clue if its posible to have a join on the table itself which will resolve this.
the only think I can think of is some sort of nested SQL query.
but besides that I am not sure if that will work. I am also concerned this will eat resources and have a great impact on the performance.

Comment: Woah woah woah. What's this SET value doing in your ID?

Comment: could you provide an example of the output that you are aiming for?

Comment: @Zane the id was never set to be numeric only. so the DB got filled over the years with named entries.

Comment: Improper data types strike again!

Comment: How do you know which children belong to which parent if they are all id'd by `SET`?

Comment: Not all parents are called SET they all have unique names (changed it in the example)

Answer (score 0):

As long es you have only 1 level, just add the following order criterion to your SQL:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(parent, id), rowlevel
```

(Assuming that `-none-` is actually `null` and `SET`/`-SET -` is actually some kind of numeric id.)

If you have more than 1 level of nesting, you will require some kind of recursive CTE.

Comment: is this assuming that `-none-` as actually a `null`?

Comment: @dav1dsm1th: Yes, and it also assumes that `SET` is actually some numeric id.

Comment: sadly "set" isnt Always numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t1.[id], t1.[description], t1.[parent], 
           [rowlevel]  = 0
    FROM dbo.Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.parent = '-none-'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.[id], t2.[description], t2.[parent], 
           [rowlevel]  = CTE.[rowlevel] + 1
    FROM dbo.Table1 t2 INNER JOIN CTE
        ON t2.parent = CTE.id
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY rowlevel, id
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6d3e/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: Tried this one but unless i did something wrong it still results in sorted Childeren and sorted parents. but not stacked, as i need them.
Its pretty close though, ill give it another go tomorrow